# What models are good at dealing with interactions between features?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, interaction

I have a data set where I suspect many times attributes are only predictive when interacting with another attribute.

What machine learning model would you choose to deal with this issue? Which would you not choose?

Comment: You can put interaction terms of interest into vanilla OLS linear regression. Do you mean having the model find the interaction terms on its own without you having to specify?

Comment: To be honest both. I know some features interact, however for some I want to find out more.